# Fixed size custom View's UI components is not visible on screen

Tags: android

I have a **fixed size custom view** as follow.

### RateAppBanner.java

```
public class RateAppBanner extends LinearLayout {

    public RateAppBanner(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rate_app_banner, this, true);

        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        View view = this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if (view == null) {
            Log.i("CHEOK", "WTF!");
        } else {
            // Reach here!
            Log.i("CHEOK", "---> " + ((TextView)view).getText());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
       int w = 320;
       int h = 100;
       setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
    }

}
```

### rate_app_banner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffff0000"
        android:text="Hello World" />
</merge>
```

However, I realize the `textView1` is not visible on screen, even thought I can find it through `findViewById`.

I use the dump View Hierarchy through Eclipse. Here's what I get.

[image]

**This puzzles me a lot. I can't see `textView1` in the view hierarchy, even I can discover it through `findViewById`**. Do you have any idea why `textView1` is not visible on screen?

This is how I add `RateAppBanner` into my main activity.

### MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.screen_main);
        mainView.addView(new RateAppBanner(this));
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/screen_main">
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

### Complete source code

The complete workable souce code, which compiled using Eclipse can be downloaded from [abc.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jacz66ixbuubm72/abc.zip?dl=0)

*p/s The code example shown in `rate_app_banner.xml` is a stripped down version of complex UI layout. To narrow down the problem scope, I make the layout file contain only single `TextView`.*

### Another approach

Instead of using `merge`, I had tried

### rate_app_banner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffff0000"
        android:text="Hello World" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It doesn't work still...

Comment: Do you ever **include** the **merged** component?

Comment: Can you further elaborate on `include the merged component`? I thought `inflate(R.layout.rate_app_banner, this, true)` really mean, "attach all UI components in rate_app_banner.xml, into this RateAppBanner Linear Layout" ?

Comment: Not exactly. You posted this question (something similar) yesterday and I gave you an answer on that subject. Then I realized that probably my answer wasn't completely answering your question and retired it. Let me retrieve the meaningful parts of it, since the question has changed.

Comment: No... I'm not able to find the old question. I'll have to rewrite the answer. It was somehow elaborated, it will take me some time.

Comment: Try changing your inflate line to `addView( LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rate_app_banner, this, false))`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Oh, I didn't really try out your proposed answer, as my custom layout file will contain more than 1 component. The reason you see I only post 1 component, because I want to narrow down the problem scope. I rephrase my question, along with complete working code. Hopefully this time, I can express my problem in a clearer form. Thank you.

Comment: I re-answered, hope this will help you somehow.

Comment: I tested using your source abc.zip. Please change the red color of text view to other. then add
<code>
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, intheightMeasureSpec) {
    int w = 320;
    int h = 200;
    super.onMeasure(w, h);
    setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
    }<code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested using your source abc.zip. Please change the red color of text view to other. then add
onMeasure(w, h);

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
>    int w = 320;
>    int h = 200;
>    super.onMeasure(w, h);
>    setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
> }
> ```

Comment: Ya. Having to call super.onMeasure is the key to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: Note, the solution isn't 100% workable as we shouldn't directly pass w and h value to super. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203360/proper-way-override-fixed-size-custom-view

Comment: yup. I recommend you the book Expert Android from Satya http://www.amazon.com/Expert-Android-Satya-Komatineni/dp/1430249501 inside describe proper way to create custom view