# Proper way override fixed size custom view

Tags: android

I have a custom view with Yellow background. I plan to add a Red background `TextView`, with **match_parent** for both width and height on it. Here's what I had done.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.screen_main);
        RateAppBanner rateAppBanner = new RateAppBanner(this);
        mainView.addView(rateAppBanner);
    }
}
```

### RateAppBanner.java

```
public class RateAppBanner extends LinearLayout {

    public RateAppBanner(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rate_app_banner, this, true);

        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }
}
```

### rate_app_banner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:background="#ffff0000"
        android:text="Hello World" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Now, I would like to have a **fixed width & height** custom view. I realize, after I'm having fixed width & height custom view, the added `TextView` doesn't obey **match_parent** attribute.

Here's the change I had done on custom view.

### RateAppBanner.java

```
public class RateAppBanner extends LinearLayout {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int desiredWidth = 320;
        int desiredHeight = 50;

        desiredWidth = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, desiredWidth, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        desiredHeight = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, desiredHeight, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        super.onMeasure(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
        //MUST CALL THIS
        setMeasuredDimension(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
    }
```

I realize the added `TextView` doesn't **match_parent** anymore!

[image]

Now, we can see the Yellow custom view is having fixed size 320x50. I expect the Red `TextView` will fill up the entire custom view due to **match_parent** attribute.

However, that's not the case. I believe my implementation for custom view's `onMeasure` isn't correct. May I know what is the correct way to fix this?

The complete source code can be downloaded from [abc.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gg8wv6fffqewygr/abc-fixed-size-problem.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After lots of trial and error and doing research work, final found answer.

You have set measurements for layout but not for child view, so for that you need to put this in onMeasure method,

```
        super.onMeasure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
```

Reference link : [Inflated children of custom LinearLayout don't show when overriding onMeasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394181/inflated-children-of-custom-linearlayout-dont-show-when-overriding-onmeasure)

And finally it's working :)